# Syntax for declaring pointer to over-aligned type

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

What is the syntax for declaring a pointer to an aligned type? Is there ever ambiguity between a pointer to an aligned array of objects and a pointer to an array of objects, each of which is aligned?

For example, how would I implement `foo` without a `using` or a `typedef`?

```
template <class T, int N>
using Aligned alignas(N) = T;

void foo(Aligned<float, 64>* vals, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i)
        vals[i] *= 2.0f;
}

// the above seems a bit ambiguous -- maybe it could be a pointer to
// floats that are each 64 byte aligned? -- but it gives the same
// code as the following so it seems to be doing the right thing
void bar(float* vals, int size)
{
    vals = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(vals, 64);
    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i)
        vals[i] *= 2.0f;
}
```

Comment: The code failed to compile on clang.

Comment: @kennytm Interesting. It compiles on gcc 6.1.1 with no warnings.